# How do I determine the number of arguments a function takes in Haxe?

Tags: function, reflection, haxe

How can I determine the number of arguments a function takes in Haxe?

I've looked at the [Reflect](http://api.haxe.org/Reflect.html) and [Type](http://api.haxe.org/Type.html) APIs without success.  In [AS3](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8257062/457586) and [JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/length), you can do `Function#length`.  Similar reflective abilities are available for most, if not all, of the other Haxe targets.  Combined with Haxe's detailed type system, there must be a way to determine a function's number of argument that I'm overlooking.

Comment: If you target as3 or js, you can go untyped and still access the length.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I ended up going the macro route and here's what I came up with.

```
import haxe.macro.Context;
import haxe.macro.Type;
import haxe.macro.Expr;

class Main {
    static function main() {
        function test1(a, b, c) {}
        function test2() {}
        trace(numberOfArgs(test1));  // 3
        trace(numberOfArgs(test2));  // 0
        trace(numberOfArgs(function test3(a, b) {}));  // 2
        trace(numberOfArgs('test')); // null
    }

    macro static function numberOfArgs(f:Expr):ExprOf<Null<Int>> {
        var fType:Type = Context.typeof(f);
        if (Reflect.hasField(fType, 'args')) {
            var fArgs:Array<Dynamic> = Reflect.field(fType, 'args');
            return macro $v{fArgs[0].length};
        } else {
            return macro null;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If these functions are members of a class that you can get run time type information for, then you could add the `@:rtti` annotation to the class and look up those fields in the RTTI structure. See: http://haxe.org/manual/cr-rtti-structure.html

In particular `CFunction` takes a list of arguments and the length of that would be what you want, and that will be in the RTTI. Something like:

```
@:rtti
class Main {
    public static function main():Void {
        var rtti = haxe.rtti.Rtti.getRtti(Main);
        trace(rtti); // Search in rtti->fields for foo
    }

    public function foo(a:Int, b:Int, c:Float, d:String):Void {
    }
}
```

The best solution depends on your use-case though. It could also be possible to write a macro to get just the number of parameters at compile time.